# R-L Transients Storage Phase: "Inductors" Help?

Tags: inductor, analysis, inductance

The below expression is for finding the induced voltage across the coil (inductor) at a certain Time Interval. Furthermore, the additional expressions are to find the induced voltage at 1T and 5T. I would like to know if I'm doing this correct.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I get a time constant of 31.3 µs — it looks like you ignored the effects of R1.

E, R1 and R2 can be combined to create an equivalent Thévenin source with an open-circuit voltage of 6.803 V and a series impedance of 319.7 Ω. These are the values you should use for computing the transient response.

The voltage across the inductor V<sub>L</sub> will start out at the voltage of the Thévenin source and then decay to zero as time goes on and the current builds up to the final value. The general form is:

V<sub>L</sub> = V<sub>0</sub> e<sup>–T/τ</sup>

where τ is the time constant computed above. At no point should you get a voltage that's greater than the source voltage!

Comment: I get 6.80272 V as my voltage at 0T. I'm not following how you got 31.3 microseconds. Isn't T = L/Thevenin Resistance. 10m/1.47k ohms

Comment: @Shane  The Thevenin resistance is the parallel combination of R1 and R2 or 1000 ohm in parallel with 470 ohms which works out to 319.7 ohms as stated by Dave above.  The Thevenin resistance is found by zeroing all sources and looking back into the circuit.  In this case, when the 10 volt source is set to zero, looking back from the inductor are R1 and R2 in parallel.